# CNAME already exists cannot point www. in my Cloud Front Distribution

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53, serverless-framework

I am currently trying to create a distribution for the domain I own with Route 53, `runway.supply`

[image]

[image]

I created a distribution and created A and AAA records for `runway.supply` which currently routes to my static site (I am getting other server related issues when trying to fetch my data) and now want to do the same for `www.runway.supply`

However when I try to add `www.runway.supply` to the alternate cname for its distribution I get the following issue:

[image]

**CNAMEAlreadyExistsException: One or more of the CNAMEs you provided are already associated with a different resource.**

Please note that in my screenshot where www.runway.supply is alternate domain name it cannot be saved because of the error which I have screen shotted below.

[image]

This is weird because I am able to add `runway.supply` for its distribution as an alternate cname... and I own the domain and can't seem to find what resource is using it that would keep me from adding it to the distribution.

As a result of visiting www. of my domain i get the following

```
{"message":"Forbidden"}
```

Comment: Is it possible that you used the www hostname previously in API Gateway?  The headers accompanying the error message look like perhaps you have, and that would cause the error message shown in the console.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I am not sure, I checked my API gateway for any reference to it. Where would a hostname be in API gateway, could you help me triage the error in the console?

Comment: This should be under `Custom Domain Names` in the main navigation pane of the API Gateway console.  You will need to check all regions you have used.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thank you for clarifying, but i checked every region, i'm only using a single region for my api gateway, since i am using serverless framework i just deploy and specify my region in my yml file. can you describe why you the headers may indicate that?

Comment: The response headers `x-amzn-errortype` and `x-amzn-requestid` are the giveaway.  Although not conclusive, it strongly suggests an API Gateway endpoint.  There's also `X-Cache: miss from CloudFront` which could mean a normal CloudFront distribution but is also injected into error responses by an API Gateway edge-optimized endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot shows that you already have a distribution using www.runway.supply. This is the S3 bucket name that you previously created and then made into an S3 website.

Comment: Sorry, my screenshot is me showing that when i add that as a cname i get the below error. Let me edit my post  for clarity.